# vb.net get name of key from e.keydata

Tags: keypress, vb.net-2010, hotkeys

I'm making a application which uses hotkeys. In the settings form users can set a hotkey by clicking a button (Checkbox with Appearance set to button) then the button text is set to that key.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to display the name of the key to the user. When a user hits the return key (for example) it says '13'. How can show the key name to the user without having a huge if / switch statement?

My current code:

```
Private Sub SelectkeyBtn_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles SelectkeyBtn.KeyDown
    If SelectkeyBtn.Checked = True Then
        SelectkeyBtn.Text = e.KeyData
        SelectkeyBtn.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**

I found this [vb.net get name of key from e.keydata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334666/vb-net-get-name-of-key-from-e-keydata) It helped me sort of.

My code looks like this now:

```
<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function ToAscii(ByVal uVirtKey As Integer, ByVal uScanCode As Integer, ByVal lpbKeyState As Byte(), ByVal lpChar As Byte(), ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function GetKeyboardState(ByVal pbKeyState As Byte()) As Integer
End Function

Public Shared Function GetAsciiCharacter(ByVal uVirtKey As Integer) As Char
    Dim lpKeyState As Byte() = New Byte(255) {}
    GetKeyboardState(lpKeyState)
    Dim lpChar As Byte() = New Byte(1) {}
    If ToAscii(uVirtKey, 0, lpKeyState, lpChar, 0) = 1 Then
        Return Convert.ToChar((lpChar(0)))
    Else
        Return New Char()
    End If
End Function

Private Sub SelectkeyBtn_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles SelectkeyBtn.KeyDown
    If SelectkeyBtn.Checked = True Then
        SelectkeyBtn.Text = GetAsciiCharacter(e.KeyData)
        SelectkeyBtn.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This works when I press a key on my keyboard like a, z, f, e, 1, +, /..

When I press  DELETE, F2, NUMLOCK etc. the button text is empty.. (see screenshot)
[image]

David,

Comment: Seriously, no1 here knows the answer? it been 20 days since I posted this :/